# Estimating mean and st dev of a truncated gaussian curve without spike

Tags: distributions, estimation, truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

Suppose I have a black box that generates data following a normal distribution with mean m and standard deviation s. Suppose, however, that whenever it outputs a value < 0 it does not record anything (can't even tell that it's outputted such a value). We have a truncated gaussian distribution without a spike.

How can I estimate these parameters?

Comment: I changed the tag from "truncated-gaussian" to "truncation" because most answers will be potentially useful in situations involving other distributions.

Answer (score 7):

The model for your data would be:

$y_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) I(y_i > 0)$

Thus, the density function is:

$$f(y_i|-) = \frac{exp(-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2})}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma}\ (1 - \phi(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}))}$$

where,

$\phi(.)$ is the standard normal cdf.

You can then estimate the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ using either maximum likelihood or bayesian methods.

Answer (score 6):

As Srikant Vadali has suggested, Cohen and Hald solved this problem using ML (with a Newton-Raphson root finder) around 1950.  Another paper is Max Halperin's "Estimation in the Truncated Normal Distribution" available on [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2281315) (for those with access).  Googling "truncated gaussian estimation" produces lots of useful-looking hits.

---

Details are provided in a thread that generalizes this question (to truncated distributions generally).  See [Maximum likelihood estimators for a truncated distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48897).  It might also be of interest to compare the Maximum Likelihood estimators to the Maximum Entropy solution given (with code) at [Max Entropy Solver in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21173).

Answer (score 2):

With having a technical border TB for $a=0$ a simplified approach by [H. Schneider](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824775910) is very usefull to calculate the mean $\mu_t$ and standard deviation $\sigma_t$ of the truncated normal distribution:

1. calculate the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$ (entire population!) for the data set:

   $\mu = \bar{x}= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$

   $\sigma = s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$
2. check if the technical border $TB=a=0$ has a valid distance to the average $\bar{x}$:

   consideration of $TB = a$ is not necessary when $\bar{x} \le 3s$
3. calculate $\omega, P_3(\omega), P_4(\omega)$ and $Q(\omega)$:

   $\omega = \frac{s^2}{(a-\bar{x})^2}$

   $P_3(\omega) = 1+5,74050101\omega - 13,53427037\omega^2 + 6,88665552\omega^3$

   $P_4(\omega) = -0,00374615 + 0,17462558\omega - 2,87168509\omega^2 + 17,48932655\omega^3 - 11,91716546\omega^4$

   $Q(\omega) = \frac{P_4(\omega)}{P_3(\omega)}$
4. check if $\omega \le 0,57081$, otherwise the mean $\mu_t$ is $<0$ which is not useful technically
5. calculate $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ for the truncated normal distribution:

   $\mu_t = \bar{x} + Q(\omega) \cdot (a-\bar{x})$

   $\sigma_{t}^{2} = s^2 + Q(\omega) \cdot (a-\bar{x})^2$

That's all...