# Are all types of Censoring equally harmful?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, survival

I posted these questions on the (negative) impact of Censoring in Survival Analysis;

- [Why is large amounts of censoring bad in survival analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636114/why-is-large-amounts-of-censoring-bad-in-survival-analysis)
- [How does Censoring in Survival Analysis impact Confidence Intervals?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636202/how-does-censoring-in-survival-analysis-impact-confidence-intervals)

I now have a more specific question - are all types of censoring (e.g. Left, Right, Interval) equally bad (e.g. contribute to larger variance estimates) in Survival Analysis?

For example, suppose there is a medical study in which all patients start the study at the same point in time, and not a single patient drops out of the study. However, not all the patients experience the event (i.e. right censoring).

Intuitively, I would have thought that this scenario is more desirable compared to censoring from patient drop out - you can confidently say that you observed patients throughout the entire duration of the study and did not observe events in certain patients. This sounds more ideal than a situation where patients dropped out - even though in both cases patients dropped out, the censoring in the first case seems more "informative" compared to the first second case. You are more certain about your uncertainty.

For example, consider the AFT Cure Model, used in situations where a significant percent of the patients never experience the event:

$$Y = \begin{cases} 
T = \exp(\beta^T X + \sigma W), & \text{with probability } 1 - p \\
\infty, & \text{with probability } p 
\end{cases}$$

$$L(\beta, \sigma, p | X, Y) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} [(1 - p) f(y_i | x_i, \beta, \sigma)]^{d_i} [p + (1 - p) S(y_i | x_i, \beta, \sigma)]^{1 - d_i}$$

where:

- $Y$ is the observed survival time,
- $T$ is the survival time for the susceptible individuals,
- $p$ is the proportion of the population that is cured (i.e. never experience the event).
- $f(y_i | x_i, \beta, \sigma)$ is the density function of the survival time for the susceptible individuals,
- $S(y_i | x_i, \beta, \sigma)$ is the survival function for the susceptible individuals,
- $d_i$ is the event indicator (1 if the event occurred, 0 otherwise).

Is the primary advantage of this modelling approach to fight against the negative impact of right censored patients on confidence interval/variance estimates? Even though we have full information on these patients throughout the duration of the medical study - since they still did not experience the event, they are still censored and will create problems during the estimation process? Thus, right censoring appears to be as harmful to the estimation process compared to left censoring or interval censoring?