# Derivation/Properties of Nonparametric Survival Function Hypothesis Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, survival, nonparametric

Suppose two samples of right-censored failure time data:
$$\boldsymbol{X_1} = \{(X_{i1}, \delta_{i1}) = (\min(T_{i1}, C_{i1}), 1_{T_{i1} < C_{i1}}): i = 1, ..., n_1$$
$$\boldsymbol{X_2} = \{(X_{i2}, \delta_{i2}) = (\min(T_{i2}, C_{i2}), 1_{T_{i2} < C_{i2}}): i = 1, ..., n_2$$
where $T_{ij}$ are the underlying failure times and $C_{ij}$ are the censoring times. Suppose for each sample, the failure times are distributed according to survival functions $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively. We are interested in testing whether $S_{T_2}(t) = S_{T_1}^\beta(t)$ and so we propose the hypotheses:
$$H_0: \beta = 1, H_1: \beta \neq 1$$
Deriving the log-likelihood function for $\beta$ and differentiating with respect to $\beta$, we obtain the score function under the null hypothesis:
$$S(\beta=1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_{2}} \left\{ \delta_{i2} + \log(S_{T_2}(X_{i2})) \right\}$$

Questions:

1. Is the expected value of the score function equal to 0? How can one show this?
2. How does this likelihood based test reduce to the log-rank test? Is there any connection?
3. Are there any references to formal likelihood based testing procedures for survival analysis?

Comment: Just to clarify: is $\beta$ simply an exponent, so that you can write $\log  S_{T_2}(t) = \beta \log  S_{T_1}(t)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a proportional hazards model. The [hazard function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function#Properties) $h(t)$ is:

$$h(t)=-\frac{d\ln S(t)}{dt}.$$

If $\ln S_2(t) = \beta \ln S_1(t)$ for all $t$ as you posit, $h_2(t) = \beta h_1(t)$ and $\beta$ is simply the (constant) hazard ratio $h_2(t)/h_1(t)$. All the standard results under proportional hazards for equivalence of the score and log-rank tests, asymptotic equivalence of score and likelihood-ratio tests (a general result for likelihood-based models), etc., follow.

For a a reference on likelihood-based analysis of survival data that covers non-parametric, semi-parametric, and parametric models, I continue to refer to Klein and Moeschberger's [Survival Analysis](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991) from 2003. Section 3.5 shows the forms of likelihood construction for all types of truncated and censored data, which I've summarized [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/530456/28500). Applications and examples abound therein.