# fitting left censored models using software for right censored data

Tags: survival, likelihood, censoring

When analyzing a lognormal data with left-censored values using a regression model, I have read that you can use methods that fit right-censored data but “flip” the data by subtracting from some large constant. Why does this work? Why are the coefficients the same?

This [link](https://practicalstats.com/resources/NADA-resources/NADAforR_Examples.pdf) describes the NADA package: "The routines in NADA for R internally flip the original data by subtraction from a large
constant, in order to produce right-censored values that can be input to survival analysis
routines."

The survreg library in R has the option for "type=left", but I am not clear on the correspondence, and I would like to see the equations and make survreg match NADA.

Comment: I would be surprised if this worked. Do you have a reference? What software are you hoping to use?

Comment: Are you talking about a parametric regression model? If so, you can use the [likelihood contribution from left-censored observations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/530456/28500) directly. I don't see how that time-reversal trick will work for a fully parametric AFT (e.g., lognormal) model. Also, how sure are you that the data are actually left censored? [Klein and Moeschberger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991) suggest this method in Section 5.2 for getting product-limit estimates with left censoring, but continue to say "Examples of pure left censoring are rare."

Comment: Yes, I was referring to a lognormal parametric regression for left-censored observations. In some fields, these are called "non-detects" and there are a few textbooks devoted to this topic, such as Dennis Helsel's "Nondetects and data analysis". This book is often cited as a reference for the reversal trick, but I don't have access to the book.

Answer (score 0):

If the only censoring is left censoring, as you can have with chemical concentrations that are below a detection limit, that "time"-reversal (here, concentration-reversal) method will work for getting nonparametric, Kaplan-Meier-type curves. With left censoring, [Klein and Moeschberger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991) suggest in Section 5.2

> instead of measuring time from the origin we fix a large time $\tau$ and define new times by $\tau$ minus the original times. The data set based on these reverse times is now right-censored and the estimators in sections 4.2–4.4 can be applied directly.

That's not, however, the way that the [NADA package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NADA) handles parametric regression models. For that, according to the [manual page for `cenlme()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NADA/NADA.pdf):

> This routine is a front end to the survreg routine in the survival package

which directly uses the appropriate [contributions to the likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/530456/28500) from left-censored observations in a parametric model.

Comment: Looking at the source [link](https://github.com/cran/NADA/blob/master/R/cen.R), it appears there is subtraction from a constant and then it is passed to survreg.

Comment: @julieth see [this page](https://github.com/cran/NADA/blob/master/R/reg.R), line 224 to see what happens with a regression model. Even if your define the outcome in the NADA package's `Cen()` format, for a regression model it just puts it back into a standard `Surv()` object for `survreg()` via the NADA package's `asSurv()` function. That `Cen()` format seems only to be used for models where it makes sense.