# Are there any reason to divide the MLE of a left truncated survival data with its surviving function at d, where d is the left truncation point?

Tags: survival

I am confused by this part when trying to revise the parts on survival analysis. As I understand if I want to estimate the MLE I can, in most cases, take the first derivative on that parameter and set the value to zero to find the maximum.

Even if I am interested in the fisher information, the survival function at d disappears under differentiation.

Is there any reason, assuming d is constant of x, to keep the 1/S(d) when constructing the MLE? Thanks

Comment: Although`d` represents a time of either left truncation or left censoring, it's not clear what you are representing by `x` in your question or what you mean by "assuming d is constant of x." Left censoring and left truncation are fundamentally different, while the title to the question includes both. The answer depends on which you mean. Please edit the question to provide that information, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM thanks, removed

Answer (score 2):

With left truncation of survival times, the idea is that the observation of an event at time $x$ is conditional upon having already survived until left-truncation time $Y_L$. You have no information about any events that might have happened prior to $Y_L$.

Expressing that idea in mathematical form, the [contribution to likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/530456/28500) from an event at time $x$ given left truncation at time $Y_L$ is:

$$L \propto f(x; \theta)/S(Y_L; \theta).$$

Here, $f(x; \theta)$ is the event density function at the event time $x$, $S(t; \theta)$ is the associated survival function, and $\theta$ is the vector of parameter values to be estimated.

So for a left-truncated observation it isn't just $S(Y_L; \theta)$ that you are optimizing, as your question suggests. That's combined with optimizing $f(x; \theta)$ at the observed event time, given that the individual had survived to time $Y_L$. You need to keep both in the likelihood.

Comment: Thanks, but my concern is how meaningful the S is. As it just seems redundant in finding the MLE and Fisher information. Is it for other uses like conducting log-likelihood tests

Comment: @PrestonLui omitting the S would give the incorrect contribution of the observation to the likelihood for a left-truncated case. Without it, all you have is the same contribution, f(x), as for an uncensored and untruncated observation. You can still find an MLE, but it would be the wrong MLE. S appears in some form in all likelihood contributions involving censoring or truncation; see the page linked from the answer.