# Right-censoring Survivability with Custom Likelihood Function

Tags: survival, reliability, censoring

I am having bit of difficultly understanding the process of using censored data. I know there are plenty of R packages that can do this for the usual two-parameter Weibull likelihood formula, but I would like to apply it on an extended Weibull model that incorporates more parameters. Hence the need to incorporate a custom likelihood that can estimate these extra parameters. I'm also confused as to whether I can apply this to data where the equipment does not all have the same start time.

Say I have some likelihood function, *f(t)*, and some reliability function *R(t)* that incorporates the extra parameters. I also have a dataset that has both failed and un-failed equipment, associated with their current operating age. According to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAIQI.png), the censored likelihood is:

[image]

where "*r is the number of failures and n is the number at risk.*"

Say I have the following data:

```
equip_id age           failed
       1 22.50548      0
       2 31.79649      1
       3 32.53883      1
       4 21.90784      0
       5 38.48035      1
```

I'm assuming that n=5 and r=3. So the first iteration would be:

*f(31.79649) x [R(38.48035)]^(5-3)*

second iteration is:

*f(32.53883) x [R(38.48035)]^(5-3)*

and third iteration is:

*f(38.48035) x [R(38.48035)]^(5-3)*

With the likelihood value being the joint probability across these iterations. (in practice using the log-likelihood to avoid precision loss).

Is this the appropriate way to perform this on this type of data?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAIQI.png) Ebeling, C.E., 2019. An introduction to reliability and maintainability engineering. Waveland Press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to the reference you cite, but I think that formula only works when all censoring times are the same, at $t_r$, and has an ambiguity that is leading to some confusion.

[This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/145164/28500) and its links provides the general form of the likelihood for observed, censored, and truncated times to events.
The first factor in your likelihood product, $f(t_i| \theta_1,\dots \theta_k)$, is the contribution from cases with exact observed event times $t_i$. $R(t_r)$ is the contribution to likelihood from a right-censored observation at time $t_r$, the survival function at that time.

I think that $[R(t_r)]^{n-r}$ (a) is intended to be *outside of the product* over the $r$ observed event times, and (b) only can be used that way if all right-censoring times are at $t_r$. With that interpretation, the formula makes sense. That's not the case in general, however.

The likelihood for your example data would be proportional to:

$$R(22.5)\times f(31.8) \times f(32.5) \times R(21.9) \times f(38.5)$$

with the implied dependence of $f$ and $R$ on the parameter values.

If you can define your probability density for events as a function of parameters properly, then the [`flexsurv` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=flexsurv) should be able to fit it to your data.

It's not clear what you mean by "the equipment does not all have the same start time." In general you define `time = 0` with respect to the particular probability model that you have in mind. That would typically be the time at which a piece of equipment was put into service, and the event/censoring time would be relative to that. If you think that the actual calendar time of entry into service affects the reliability, then you might include that as a covariate in a parametric model in which the values of some of the Weibull parameters are a function of the calendar date of entry into service.

Comment: This is a wonderful explanation that really clarifies the use and intent of the likelihood function. As far as the start time concern, you nailed it, I wasn't sure if calendar time/seasonality is an issue, but I can start without it as a more generalized case. If there's a particular charity that you like, I'd be happy to make a small donation as a thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @coolhand I'd ask that you help in some way occasionally with a web question-and-answer site. Not necessarily this one, but one that might have some more direct importance to you. For example, beyond answering questions on this site, a lot of behind-the-scenes effort goes into editing questions to fix formatting and to bring questions into the site's preferred form, to add useful tags to help searches, to flag inappropriate questions for a moderator's interventions, and to comment on questions to clarify an OP's intent (which all too often isn't initially clear).

Comment: Will do and thank you for pointing me towards `flexsurv` package. I pouring over the documentation and think it will make implementation easier.